# Memory leak in NSString stringWithUTF8String: with ARC enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

In my application i have enabled the ARC. But in my application following lines gives me memory leaks according to instruments. It is in ios 7.0.

```
-(id)init{
    variables = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] init]; // Leak
    events = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] init]; //Leak
    return self;

}
```

### Update

But in my app if i do something like below it does not show me any leak. But i can't add items in to the variables.

```
-(id)init{
    variables = [[[NSMutableArray  alloc] init] copy]; // No Leak
    events = [[[NSMutableArray  alloc] init] copy]; //No Leak
    return self;

}
```

--

```
NSString *utfString =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)attr->children->content];//Leak
```

--

```
-(NSObject*)createObjectForClass:(NSString*)className{
    Class cls = NSClassFromString(className);
    NSObject *object = [[cls alloc]init]; //Leak
    if(cls != nil){
        CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(cls));
    }
    return object;
}
```

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you calling `CFRelease` on `cls`?

Comment: rmaddy, I tried by doing that. In first place i thought it was the problem

Comment: You don't own `cls`, don't release it. It will crash your app.

Comment: show some more code, above code which is not cause for leak if ARC enabled.

Comment: Your init method also doesn't follow Cocoa best practices / conventions. You're not calling `[super init]` or checking the return value.

Comment: why do you call alloc & init and moreover a copy?

Comment: @viperking what i wanted to show is if i assign NSArray to my local variable. It works fine. But if i assign Mutable object then it shows me memory leak.

Comment: could you check whether id<NSObject*> instead of NSObject* will help?

Comment: calling copy on NSMutableArray returns NSArray (which is immutable), that's why you can't add items to it.

Comment: @Michał Ciuba My problem is when it is Mutable im having memory leak. Is there any solution for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory Leak -- Objective C with ARC enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762378/memory-leak-objective-c-with-arc-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

My guess right now is that your entire object is leaking, which means that the `NSMutableArray`s created in `-init` also leak. The version that calls `copy` isn't leaking because the copy is probably returning a singleton instance of `NSArray` (as there are zero elements in it, and it's an immutable NSArray, there's probably a singleton instance for that).